# Core Data generates an NSManagedObject subclass with a property of type NSNumber, but it's a Bool

Tags: swift, core-data

I just created a Core Data data model and added some entities. Now I'm generating `NSManagedObject` subclasses.

In the generated code, I found that one of my properties, whose type is "Boolean" in the data model, has turned into a property of type `NSNumber`!

That's not correct, I thought. An `NSNumber` is certainly not a boolean. Why doesn't it just use the `Bool` type?

Then I thought that this might be another one of those annoying things of Objective-C. I think that just like `Int` and `Double`, a `Bool` cannot be saved into Core Data so it has to use an `NSNumber`. Am I right?

How to convert this `NSNumber` to a `Bool` and how to convert a `Bool` to an `NSNumber`?  Maybe 0 = false and 1 = true? What about other values? This isn't type-safe at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your question `How to convert this NSNumber to a Bool and how to convert a Bool to an NSNumber?` u can do like below, for `NSNumber` objects

```
//convert bool to number 
NSNumber *boolInNumber = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]; //or NO

//get back, convert number to bool 
NSNumber *aNum = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]; //get the NSNumber instance
BOOL numberInBool = [aNum boolValue];
```

and aslo u can convert to other types, for more info check the class reference [hear](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/)

sorry for the delay, and for **swift version**,

```
  var numInBool:NSNumber? //is a nsnumber instance
  numInBool = NSNumber(bool: true) //get number from bool (number in bool)

  var boolInNum:Bool? //it is boolean
  boolInNum = numInBool!.boolValue  //get bool from number (bool from number)
```

yes you are right... :) as per @fred doc said,

```
let numInBool =     NSNumber(bool: true) 
let boolInNum =     numInBool.boolValue
```

Comment: I am not that good at reading Objective-C code. To avoid confusion and misunderstanding, can you also show the solution in Swift? Also, am I right about `I think that just like Int and Double, a Bool cannot be saved into Core Data so it has to use an NSNumber`?

Comment: You are right about CoreData. In Swift, should be something like this :

Comment: You are right about CoreData. In Swift, should be something like this : 
let test = NSNumber(bool: true)
test.boolValue
But I'm pretty sure swift does type inference :-)